# Get the nth item at an offset to the first/last in a std::set

Tags: c++, iterator, set

So if you want to get the first/last item in a `std::set<int>` I know you can use:

```
int j = *(my_set.begin());
```

but I have the above code in a loop and I'd like to have something like:

```
while(something){
    int j = *(my_set.begin() + i);
    //
    i++;
}
```

but I get a compiler error saying no operator "+=" matches these operands.

Comment: `int j = *(std::next(my_set.begin(), i));`

Comment: Get an error on the dereferencer saying "operand of "*" must be a pointer"

Answer (score 3):

You can do something using iterators, like this:

```
for(auto it = begin(your_set); it != end(your_set); ++it){
  //Here you iterator for i'th element in i'th iteration.
  *it; //<--i'th element
 }
//your_set.begin(), your_set.end() in older versions of C++
```

But maybe better way for you is use [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), like here:

```
for(auto& x : your_set) {
  //You have here i'th element of set (by reference) 
  x; //<-- i'th element
 }
//Without & x isn't reference
```

For i'th element you can use [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

```
j = *next(begin(my_set), i);
```

but... using std::next each time is deadly for complexity. Set has not [Random Access Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), and function std::next (using [advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), what is linear for [Bidirectional Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator)) returns position linearly. And for n elements, you have **Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)** complexity, if  you want to use each element once and you using the methods presented above you have **Θ(n)**.